# bezier shape-fill: problem with finding roots for intersection test

Tags: floating-point, glsl, complex-numbers, bezier, newtons-method

I adapted [this shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/sdjBRy) into a Unity shader and have noticed that, while it generally works as expected, there are certain artifacts that appear, as I will further explain. I believe they are related to the calculation of roots in the Bezier curves.

Below is a visualization of the artifact. First picture shows the Bezier shape with artifact, second picture shows the Bezier shape in earlier animation frames, working correctly:

[image: Artifact]

[image: Working correctly, earlier frame]

I seemed to have narrowed down the origin of the artifact to the function that calculates the Bezier roots. When I only visualize the shape outline, there are no artifacts. Artifacts are introduced when applying the method that fills in the shape using the [even-odd intersection test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule).

The Bezier shape is animated: In other words, the Vector2 positions that define the control points of the Bezier curve  change over time (they linearly interpolate between two defined positions). At most frames behavior is expected, however, at certain frames (or positions) the artifacts appear.

The fill-rule basically counts intersections between the Bezier curve and horizontal lines at each uv.y coordinate, where a given horizontal line acts as the x-axis for the Bezier function and the roots of the function represents points that intersect with this x-axis. However, some of the roots will be complex numbers (i.e. they have a real and imaginary component, a + bi), which I think might cause the issue. However, the function that calculates the roots (starting at line 74) evidently discards complex roots, because I read the annotations where they link their sources and [one of the sources](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/) is clearly where the shadertoy author got this function from: the cited article describes how this function discards complex roots. See "Implementing Cardano's algorithm for finding all real roots" about 1/4 the way down.

I am scratching my head. Does anyone reading have experience with Bezier functions? Ever seen artifacts like this? Would really appreciate any insight.

Thanks!

I have already tried addressing "near misses" and double-counting of segments at segments' beginning and ending, since this is where segments may overlap (e.g. the point that defines the end of one Bezier segment is the exact same position that defines the beginning of the next segment). This did not solve the problem.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253215/discussion-on-question-by-mikemeyers-bezier-shape-fill-problem-with-finding-roo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is definitely the computation of the real roots of the cubic polynomial.

One first misunderstanding is the scale of the intermediate values. In the segment where the errors are produced, the coefficients of the expanded and normalized polynomial are in the range of `3*1500`. For instance at `y = 4.84400272369` the values are

```
a = -1117.05571565802, b = 1706.85975024015, c = -1828.09125840538
```

for the polynomial `t^3 + 3*a*t^2 + 3*b*t + c`.

This results in coefficients in the million and billion range for the coefficients of the reduced polynomial, in my version `s^3 - 3*p*s +q`, in the example

```
p = 1246106.61213401, q = -2782036197.45853
```

The discriminant then gets an even larger value, for the example `-178627039216.052`. This is for an `y` level close to a double root, meaning this is a "small" discriminant value.

The three real roots here are

```
0: 3349.63861387448, 1: 0.568446220187752, 2: 0.960086879399569
```

This combination of large and small roots will have an influence on the precision of the roots. The values cited above are for a computation in double precision.

---

The implementation I used for the values above employs the typical changes to compute more accurate solutions, to avoid catastrophic cancellation.

- use the `atan2` method to compute angles (overloaded `atan` in the shader math functions)
- stable computation of solutions of quadratic equations,
- stable combination of the cubic roots, use binomial theorem `A^3+B^3=(A+B)*(A^2-A*B+B^2)` if `A*B<0`.

This removes the errors in the shape of the object. The occasional flicker of one or two scan lines can be eliminated by applying one Newton step to the roots in and close to the unit interval.

---

Better still would be to avoid this escalation in the scale of the numbers.

To that end transform the input polynomial

```
A*(1-t)^3 + 3*B*(1-t)^2*t + 3*C*(1-t)*t^2 + D*t^3
```

in the case `abs(A) < abs(D)` to

```
A/D + 3*(B/D)*s + 3*(C/D)*s^2 + s^3  with  s = t/(1-t),  t = s/(1+s)
```

and in the opposite case to

```
s^3 + 3*(B/A)*s^2 + 3*(C/A)*s + D/A  with  s = (t-1)/t,  t = 1/(1+s)
```

---

In code, for the call in the counting procedure

```c
    vec3 roots = vec3(-2,-2,-2);
 ...
    if(abs(sA.y) < abs(sD.y)) {
        cubicRoots(sC.y/sD.y, sB.y/sD.y, sA.y/sD.y, roots);
        roots = roots/(1.0+roots);
    } else {
        cubicRoots(sB.y/sA.y, sC.y/sA.y, sD.y/sA.y, roots);
        roots = 1.0/(1.0+roots);
    }
```

and the modified Cardano procedure itself. Note that there are no preparatory coefficient manipulations now.

```c
void cubicRoots(float a, float b, float c, inout vec3 roots){

    // input stands for  t^3 + 3*a*t^2 + 3*b*t + c = 0
    // insert t = s-a
    
    //  s^3-3as^2+3a^2s-a^3 + 3a*(s^2-2as+a^2) + 3b*(s-a) + c
    //  s^3 + 3*(-a^2+b)*s + (2*a^3-3*a*b+c)
    // Precompute a^2 and other powers
    float a2 = a * a;

    float p = a2-b;
    float p3 = p * p * p;

    float q = (2.0*a2*a - 3.0 * a * b + c);
    float q2 = 0.5 * q;

    // equation now s^3 - 3*p*s + q = 0
    // Cardano trick s = u+v
    // u^3+v^3+q + 3*(u+v)*(u*v-p) = 0
    // u^6+p^3+q*u^3 = 0
    // (u^3+q2)^2 = q2^2-p3 = discriminant
    
    // q^2 - 4*p^3 = (4a^6+9a^2b^2+c^2-12a^4b-6abc+4a^3c) - 4*(a^6-3a^4b+3a^2b^2-b^3)
    float discriminant = 0.25*(-3.0*a2*b*b+c*c-6.0*a*b*c)+a2*a*c+b*b*b;

    if(discriminant <= 0.0){
        // Three possible real roots s=2*r*cos(phi) 
        // => r^3 * (cos(3*phi)+3*cos(phi)) - 3*p*r*cos(phi) + q2 = 0
        // r^2=p,  cos(3*phi)=-q2/sqrt(p3), sin(3*phi) = sqrt(-discriminant)/sqrt(p3)

        float r = sqrt(p);
        float phi = atan(sqrt(-discriminant), -q2);
     
        roots.x = phi;
        roots.y = phi + TWO_PI;
        roots.z = phi - TWO_PI;
        
        roots = 2.0*r*cos(roots*O3) - a;      

    } else if(discriminant < -1e-6) {
        // Three real roots, but two of them are equal
        // s^3 - 3*p*s + q = (s+u)^2 * (s-2*u) = s^3 - 3*u^2*s - 2*u^3               
        float u1 = -cuberoot(q2);
        roots.x = 2.0 * u1;
        roots.y = roots.z= -u1;
        roots -= a;
    } else {  // discriminant > 0, one real root, two complex roots
        float sd = sqrt(discriminant);
        if(q2<0.0) sd = -sd;
        float u = -cuberoot(q2+sd);
        float v = p/u;
        roots.x = (p>=0.0)?(u+v-a):(-q/(u*u-p+v*v)-a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @LutzLehmann for what seems to be a very precise and well-explained answer. Afraid it is over my head for the moment, need to research a lot more to be able to implement your recommendations. Are you saying that in my code, I can use the same method (Cardano's method) to find the roots for those last two functions instead of the current bezier function, and this will correct the artifact?

Comment: Yes. The polynomial coefficients that result this way are much less problematic, in the segment in question they are all smaller than 1, there are no large roots (for s). I did not test against the original Cardano implementation, only against one with the points mentioned. There are still counter-examples, like when the end points lie on the same  level, A=D, as do the control points, B=C. Then the input coefficients could have A=D=0. This would require a separate treatment, I have no good idea at the moment.

Comment: Isolating the single segment, your code does indeed fix the original problem with the roots: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/mld3z7       any idea where those extra roots are coming from outside of the segment bounds?

Comment: Sorry forgot to make public. Should work now!

Comment: Yes, it is there. Why did you leave the first `cuberoot` call in? You pre-load `roots` with the roots of a different polynomial, and if the proper call does not overwrite them, they remain in the calculation. Removing that line removes the artifact.

Comment: It works perfectly, carried over into my Unity project, seen here on the right hand side: https://giphy.com/gifs/8VC2VnOIpGSMOnSUYG. Thank God for mathematic/engineering minds. If you want to email me your venmo, apple pay, or paypal username I would be glad to send you $50.00. email is jsmithir123@gmail.com. Thank you!