TOMS 748 - "the bounds given must bracket a single root"?
I have a cubic equation f(x)=0 which I need to solve numerically to within some tolerance. I only need one of the roots.
I already have values a and b such that f(a) and f(b) have opposite signs; i.e. the interval [a,b] is known to bracket at least one root.
I am considering using the Boost.Math implementation of TOMS 748. However, the documentation states:

f(x) need not be uniformly increasing or decreasing on x and may have
multiple roots. However, the bounds given must bracket a single root.

I can only guarantee that [a,b] brackets at least one root, not exactly one root. So my question is whether this is really a requirement, and why? (My understanding was that pretty much all bracketing-based numerical root finders fall back to bisection as a last resort.)
As an aside, the Boost.Math documentation also says it does not include an implementation of Brent's Method because TOMS 748 is "superior and provides equivalent functionality". But these statements cannot both be true, since Brent's Method has no such restriction, correct?

Good question. I wonder whether it will work better on Math.SE but I really cannot assess either way, just a suggestion that you might use.

Python's scipy.optimize.toms748 has no such limitation. This is likely just poorly worded documentation.

@njuffa I have actually seen your other answers. In my case, I naturally have bounds containing a root and I want high precision, so the derivative-less approaches with guaranteed convergence are a better fit IMO. At the moment my top candidates are TOMS 758 from Boost and Brent's Method from GSL.

@yurikilochek Thank you. That is what I figured after staring at the TOMS 758 paper this afternoon. I will see about submitting a bug report against the documentation.

Another option to consider for a cubic solver is ACM 954 or the one used in my Kepler equation solver Appendix A. Caution it returns one root even when there are three (hardwired for that problem). If you want ultimate precision it is necessary to use the best cbrt algorithm (adequate sample in the code) - of the major compilers only Intel's cbrt is remotely good enough for this!). Slight improvement for difficult edge cases if you apply N-R to finesse the raw root(s).

A careful implementation of the Cardano formulas is faster than any iterative approach, despite or especially when using (carefully implemented) formula salad. // As to the original question, I would speculate that it is theoretically possible, even if practically super rare, that with 3 roots inside the interval the method shrinks the bracketing/guard interval to the outer roots, and not to length zero. // Another reason for this condition could be that the root selected depends on the implementation and its fine-tuning, so that the multiple-root case is not testable.

@LutzLehmann Thank you for the input.
I am pretty sure most (all?) bracketing methods fall back to bisection when they have  trouble making progress, so the interval will always shrink to whatever tolerance is desired. So the differences among these algorithms come down to speed.
I am willing to consider a Cardano based solution if it is freely available and production quality. (I lack both the time and the expertise to code one myself.) Do you know of any?

As I understand it, ACM 954 referenced by @Martin Brown already does this. My own last experiments in finding roots of cubic splines is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76073741/3088138. As always, the finished, properly working product is boring in contrast to earlier buggy versions. The aim is to identify inside points of a shape (for drawing in shadertoy) by counting intersections with a horizontal line, which went nicely wrong at connection points and points with horizontal tangent. You could check the edit history for some of these earlier versions.

What level of production quality do you need? ACM 954 is robust but I wouldn't want to vouch for it in a mission critical situation. My own code for solving Kepler's equation skips normalisation because I have strict a priori bounds on the coefficients. My priority is speed and accuracy over the domain it is intended to work in. Beware that Cardano formulas may be badly behaved in float implementations unless careful attention is paid to rescaling the coefficients. The other gotchas are edge cases 3 real roots where cos(x) is 1+eps due to rounding error in the 3 roots case. Polish with NR.
